# Sending Data from Controller to jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

[After putting $ sign getting this error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPjlv.png)

I was trying to send data from my controller to jsp page but it is only printing -->

```
{login.UserID}
{login.Password}
```

**Logincontroller.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    public final static  String WELCOME = "Welcome";
    public final static  String LOGIN = "Login";

    @RequestMapping(value ="/login" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView ShowLogin()
    {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(LOGIN);
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView LoginUser(@ModelAttribute("login") Login login)
    {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(WELCOME);
        System.out.println(login.getUserID());
        System.out.println(login.getPassword());
        //model.addObject("login",login);
        return model;       
    }
}
```

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>{login.UserID}</h1>
    <h1>{login.Password}</h1>



  </body>
</html>
```

But i am not going the value of name and password in my jsp instead i am getting -->

```
{login.UserID}
{login.Password}
```

Comment: In page tag, add `<%@ page ... isELIgnored="false" %>`, and use `${ }` for EL, not `{ }`. See [Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm) for further information.

Comment: Is SpringMvc configured to resolve jsp views? E.g. is bean of class org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver defined? Can you provide both spring mvc configuration (xml?) and web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need to include a `$` like

```
${login.UserID}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was missing out $ expression but now after putting the expression I am getting another error. Please find the attached screen shot above.

Comment: It is working fine now..The 2nd issue is also resolved..Thanks a ton! @ChristianFrommeyer I want to ask one question that I am not adding the login object to the ModelandView using the addObject() function but then how i am being able to access the login object in my Welcome.jsp page?? Does adding object to ModelAttribute automatically adds the data to the jsp page?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting your question. If this is unrelated you might want to open a new one.